"E: malformed entry 1 in list file [...]" when running `sudo apt-get update`
E: malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_deb_opera_com_opera-stable_stable-jammy.list {component}
E: The list of sources could not be read


I cannot update any new features because of that malformed entry, I uninstalled Opera Browser and still have the same error.

The error message tells you the exact line in the exact file that is wrong. Edit it into your question if you need more help.
